# How can I replace string literals with real html?

Tags: html, string

I have a repeater that I bind to a custom object that produces a couple of strings.
I know that the strings are meant to be valid HTML, and conceptually could be complex with styling and be fairly long (in the way of 2-300 words)

Currently I am making the strings like so

```
  Body = @"This is an example:
                    <ul>
                        <li>example 1</li>
                        <li>example 2</li>
                        <li>example 3</li>
                        <li>example 4</li>
                    </ul>"
```

Which "works" but I don't get any help from Visual Studio (or whatever) to know my html is valid, or help me match tags etc etc.

What is my best way of taking this string and putting it in a file or resource that will let me edit with all the help an IDE gives me, whilst still being able to get at the string value of the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create a html template file for this. Add your html in a separate .html file and then you can read the content (string) from there and can use in your code.

In this approach you can easily change your html content whenever you want without changing in the code.